# How to display to the nearest hour in moment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, momentjs

On my project requires this kind of text response on a day and hours.

"2hrs"-- data as milliseconds, If i get 1h 30mins, **It should be rounded-up to 2hrs.**

i tried so many times but cannot catch the value. now am getting 1 hrs for below function.
can anyone help me to do this ? here is the function which i am using

```
const milliSec = 85600000;
const hrs = moment(moment.duration(milliSec)._data).format('HH[hrs]');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to solve your problem

1. Simple logic

```
let milliseconds = 85600000;
let hours = Math.floor(milliseconds/(1000*3600))
let minutes = Math.floor(milliseconds/(1000*60)) - hours * 60

if(minutes > 29){
    console.log(hours + 1);
}
console.log(hours)
```

2. Using Moment.js

```
let milliseconds = 85600000
let hours = Math.floor(moment.duration(milliseconds).asHours())
let mins = Math.floor(moment.duration(milliseconds).asMinutes()) - hours * 60;

if(minutes > 29){
    console.log(hours + 1);
}
console.log(hours)
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.